# show a tag after countdown javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to show `<p id='download_link'>` after countdown and hide `<div id='countdown'>` after the tag showing.

i try like this but the hide and showing execute before countdown go to `zero`.

button to start countdown

```
<center><a href='#download_link'><input class='btn btn-success' type='submit' value='Show Download Link' style='margin-bottom:10px' onclick='countdown(5)'></a></center>
```

js to start countdown

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.btn").click(function(){
        $("div#countdown").show();
    });
});
```

here my js countdown script

```
function countdown(remaining) {
    if(remaining === 0)
    return;
        $("p#download_link").show();
        $("div#countdown").hide();  
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
    setTimeout(function(){ countdown(remaining - 1); }, 1000);
};
```

code to show countdown and the tag i want to show after countdown

```
<center><div id='countdown'></div><p id='download_link' style='display:none'>".$url_decode."</p></center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `return;` inside the function is creation problem.

It should be like

```
function countdown(remaining) {
  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = remaining;
  if (remaining === 0) {
    $("p#download_link").show();
    $("div#countdown").hide();
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    countdown(remaining - 1);
  }, 1000);
};
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjjdou26/) demo